# IOS app stuck in splash screen on IOS version 10.2.1 with no error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics

My `iOS` app was perfectly working till yesterday. My QA was testing and there was no bug at all. But when I tried to install from `Xcode` to my iPhone 6 somehow it got stuck in splash screen and debugger shows absolutely no error. I googled a lot but no luck. I even tried to run previous version by switching my current branch but no luck.

This is what my debugger look like:

> 2018-02-07 12:49:56.982145 Marham[547:85300] 4.8.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40009000 started
>   2018-02-07 12:49:56.982649 Marham[547:85300] 4.8.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see [some-Link])
>   2018-02-07 12:49:56.983029 Marham[547:85300] 4.8.1 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
>   [some-Link]to ensure proper integration.
>   (lldb)

and here is the surprising thing for me that, app runs without any issue on simulator but got stuck only on real device.

Comment: it is surprising that you live in the future. I guess you meant yesterday instead of tomorrow. Anyways, please include the code that is running and throwing this error. Also, the error itself does have some information on how to fix it.

Comment: oops, sorry I didn't notice, this error is really affecting my mind :D anyways, my debugger is not showing anything but these lines.

Comment: when I click on continue button from debugger app simply goes crash and still console shows nothing.

Comment: @Najam Are you using distribution profile for running on your device?

Comment: @QUserS nope I am not using distribution profile I have assigned development certificates.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that warning is unrelated to your crash. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: @ØyvindHauge Yes I have done that several times, even I have quit and restart my Xcode

Comment: I suspect something different. Those messages above are not Error messages but Info messages. To determine the problem, can you unlink either Firebase Analytics SDK or Firebase Messaging, or both? Or comment out [FIRApp configure] to see whether Firebase is the real problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have this issue ?
Because I had a similar one and that was because a local storage variable was blocking the execution of the first view on the phone (the simulator was working fine).

So I advise you to put your phone on debut mode and make a breakpoint on the main function in the App Delegate.

This way, you should be able to se if there's an async function waiting for nothing.